# How do I json normalize this nested structure using Pandas?

Tags: json, pandas

I have a JSON url with the following structure from [THIS](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker) url and am trying to get the name, price and volume from the structure below

```
{'data': {'1': {'id': 1,
   'name': 'Bitcoin',
   'symbol': 'BTC',
   'website_slug': 'bitcoin',
   'rank': 1,
   'circulating_supply': 17115025.0,
   'total_supply': 17115025.0,
   'max_supply': 21000000.0,
   'quotes': {'USD': {'price': 6317.68,
     'volume_24h': 5034440000.0,
     'market_cap': 108127251142.0,
     'percent_change_1h': 0.22,
     'percent_change_24h': 5.26,
     'percent_change_7d': -4.37}},
   'last_updated': 1529943576},
  '2': {'id': 2,
   'name': 'Litecoin',
   'symbol': 'LTC',
   'website_slug': 'litecoin',
   'rank': 6,
   'circulating_supply': 57133246.0,
   'total_supply': 57133246.0,
   'max_supply': 84000000.0,
   'quotes': {'USD': {'price': 84.4893,
     'volume_24h': 512241000.0,
     'market_cap': 4827147957.0,
     'percent_change_1h': 1.97,
     'percent_change_24h': 8.96,
     'percent_change_7d': -12.54}},
   'last_updated': 1529943541}},
 'metadata': {'timestamp': 1529943282,
  'num_cryptocurrencies': 1586,
  'error': None}}
```

I tried several variations to get each coin in a row but have failed so far

**Attempt 1**

```
df = pd.read_json('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker')
```

[image]

**Attempt 2**

```
data = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker',params).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
```

df

[image]

**Attempt 3**

I found this function on stackoverflow called json normalize and I tried to use it but no luck so far

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['data'])
df
```

Any suggestions on how to turn each coin into a row are super appreciated

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

```
params = {'start': 0, 'sort': 'id', 'limit': 100}
data = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker', params).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
df = df.transpose()
df.set_index('id')
```

This is pretty close to what I want, but how do I get the volume and price out of quotes

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming "quotes" only have 1 row and the key is "USD", I did this

```
df.drop('quotes', 1).join(
    pd.DataFrame(
        df.quotes.apply(
            lambda x: {'USD'+'_'+key: val for key, val in x['USD'].items()}
                       ).tolist()
                )
)
```